# Spring Transactions - how to split my method

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, transactions

I have the following method that is called by controller:

```
@Transactional
public Note getById(Long noteId, Collection<Authority> authorities) {
        permissionService.actionAllowed(authorities, Permission.NOTE);
        return getNote(noteId);
    }

 private Note getNote(Long noteId) {
        return repository.findById(noteId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new MyException("Note does not exist"));
}
```

The problem is that we should keep transactions as short as possible so I have to call my validation method `permissionService.actionAllowed` outside of the trasaction scope. How to do it in the best way?
I don't want to create additional public method with `@Transactional`... I don't have any idea

Comment: I don't like the way how you handle, i.e: First layer is `Controller` so you can add all related to api like requests, responses, headers, body, status code, sencond layer `Service`  So there you can add all related to logic like validations, bussines logic, calls to repository, the third layer is `Repository` that is all related to DB like queries, etc.

Comment: Then you can add `@Transactional`  annotation in your `Service` class in the top in order to use for all calls, or like you put on one method, so the issue here is disordered, if you keep the way ideal so you can do it much better.